# how to make a reference to a section with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

i need to make a reference to the section of my site and i don't know how ( i have just started to stdy it)
i made a .js function which agrees to change the background color of the body. i made this:

```
function changeBackground() {


var rd = parseInt(document.getElementById('red').value);
var gn = parseInt(document.getElementById('green').value);
var bl = parseInt(document.getElementById('blue').value);


var rdhex = (rd < 16) ? "0" + rd.toString(16) : rd.toString(16);
var gnhex = (gn < 16) ? "0" + gn.toString(16) : gn.toString(16);
var blhex = (bl < 16) ? "0" + bl.toString(16) : bl.toString(16);

// create a variable that concatenates all the parts
var hexcode = "#" + rdhex + gnhex + blhex;


document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexcode;
document.getElementById('hexdisplay').innerHTML = hexcode;

}
```

as u can see i applyed the changecolor to the body (second-last command line) how can i apply it to the section of the site?

Comment: Wrap it in a script tag and place it on the page

Comment: TGH, don't forget your are speaking to a novice ;)

Comment: don't forget you're talking to non english native people... so for them (like me) = 'as u can see' => 'as you can see'...       ;) Salut Romain !

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I apply it to the section of the site?"

Do this to your elements: document.getElementById('your-element').innerHTML = hexcode;

Comment: I wish I were fluent =)

Comment: how is the function triggered? onload? onclick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to define a section using a `div` tag, for example. Then, add the `id` attribute so that you can identify it.

```
<div id="leftSection"> ... </div>
```

Then, in your javascript, get the `div` element:

```
var leftSection = document.getElementById("leftSection");
leftSection.style.backgroundColor = hexcode;
```

Comment: ahahahaha thank you very much!! it works!! ^_______^